# Sending values to zipped generators

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Consider the following code:

```
def g1():
    while True:
         yield 1

def g2():
    while True:
        yield 1
        yield 2

def g3():
    while True:
        yield 1
        yield 2
        yield 3

def G():
    # Zip all three generators
    genList = [g1(), g2(), g3()]
    Z = zip(*genList)
    yield from Z

# Iterate over the zip of all three generators
for i, g in zip(range(6), G()):
    print(g)
```

The three generators g1, g2, g3 all yield simple numbers, and the outer generator G yields from the zip of those three generators. The output ends up looking like this:

```
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 1, 3)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
```

which is what I expected: the three generators were iterated over "concurrently" which is to say I didn't exhaust the first before going to the next.

However, I worry that this is a bit of a hack. It only works because the zip type in python implements the `__next__` method, which I presume gets called when I iterate over the G() generator.

But suppose I wanted to send values to my generators? i.e

```
# stop iteration if a negative value is sent
def g1():
    yield
    while True:
         input = yield 1
         if input < 0:
             break
...

# Create the generator and prime it
gen = G()
next(gen)

for i in zip(range(6)):
    g = gen.send(1)
    print(g)

gen.send(-1)
```

The zip type does not implement the `send` function, and I'm not really sure how it could be accomplished.

It should be said that my experience with generators, coroutines, and more importantly the new `yield from` syntax in python is quite minimal. I actually worry that I'm trying to shoehorn those language features into my code without really understanding what it's intended for.

Ultimately the purpose of these functions will be to return a container of strings corresponding to audio loops; the g1 generator would yield the same loop every time, the g2 generator would alternate, etc. These variations would result in a different container being returned each time it is iterated over.

It seemed to make sense to treat each loop as its own coroutine, since it is advancing independently of the others, and I wanted to try and leverage some of the language features rather than come up with a less portable object oriented solution.

However, perhaps there is something in itertools I could leverage, or maybe something using context managers instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send` just resumes from the `yield` exactly the same as a `next` call would, but passes in a value. If you use `next` instead of `send` it's like sending in a `None`.

You could use that to stop your generator execution:

```
value = yield x
if value:
    return
```

That will keep running as long as you're iterating over it (via `zip`, for-loop, or `next`) but stop when you `send` in any truthy value. However, I'm wondering why you even want to. Where do you imagine needing to do such a thing?

Also note that `itertools.cycle` already does what you seem to be trying here:

```
import itertools
c = itertools.cycle([1, 2, 3])
next(c), next(c), next(c), next(c)
# 1, 2, 3, 1, ...
```

Comment: But what would I call .send(False) on? Calling it on the generator that zips the three sub-generators raises an error because the zip type does not have a send function. I agree with you that it is a bit farfetched of a situation... I guess I'd just like to have to option to send something. And itertools.cycle does seem like it would work for the sub-generators, i.e g2 could yield from itertools.cycle([1, 2]), but I still have to combine several cycling generators to get my final container.

Comment: You don't ever need to call `.send(False)` - you just iterate over it as usual (via `for` or `zip` or `next`). You'd only need to `send` if you explicitly want to stop it, and again I'm not sure why you ever need to do that.

Comment: I guess one situation could be this: suppose each generator actually has a return statement that it hits when it stops iterating. The return value is actually another generator which then takes the previous generator's place, allowing me to chain different subgenerators based on what they return. I suppose I could handle that logic outside of the generator, I guess I just thought it would be cool to have each generator eventually return the generator that is meant to take its place.

Comment: Why would you return another generator instead of just using `yield from` to continue the stream?

Comment: How do I decide which generator to yield from? Suppose I send the generator some key, and internally it uses that key to determine which generator should come next. Then I would just yield from that generator, I suppose... is that what you meant? I think that could work, although I'm imaging the call stack growing quite large. That could be the answer, though.

Comment: Well, yeah stack depth could be an issue that way, and `return` would work better if that's the case. So you could proceed as I've outlined above, and inside the `if value:` block determine which other generator to return based on what the value is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107367/discussion-between-user1973454-and-tzaman).